# How to prevent pushing value into Array twice? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function which grabs a unique number from a data attribute in HTML. In my case it's called data-key which will have a unique number.

Now when a button is clicked next to HTML element that has a data-key, that key number is pushed into an Array.

I don't want the same number put into the array more than once.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? The way I'm imagining doing it is to check to see if that element is already in the Array first before pushing, but I feel like there is a simpler way?

**My Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/CEfxi**

Click on the [image] button to add an input value into the array.

[image]
< 6-1 gets added twice

jQuery

```
var deletedArray = [];

$('.remove_info').unbind('click').bind("click", function(event) {
    //console.log('clicked remove x');
    var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
    var key = $(this).prev().data('key');

    deletedArray.push(key);
    console.log('this value = '+value+' deletedArray = '+deletedArray);
});
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `.unbind('click').bind("click",...`?

Comment: Perhaps modify the DOM to flag that element as already having its value inserted and check that flag before inserting e.g. add `data-inserted=true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should've been a comment but put a control statement before the push function call

```
  if (deletedArray.indexOf(key) < 0) deletedArray.push(key);
```

For browser compatibility jQuery's `inArray`

```
  if ($.inArray(key, deletedArray) < 0) deletedArray.push(key);
```

Note: `indexOf` is not compatible with IE 8 and earlier

Comment: Agreed, this seems to be the way; though it might be worth showing how to use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) for those browsers that don't implement `Array.indexOf()`.

Comment: Agreed with @DavidThomas, since `jQuery` is being used, so `$.inArray()` is better, because of browser compatibility issue.

Comment: @DavidThomas i'm not too familiar with jQuery's `$.inArray()` you may edit the answer to have that alternate

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 yes it makes sense, but i don't know how to use that jQuery function so you may edit the answer to include that

Comment: Thanks! uhm the lowest browser we support is IE8, what browsers don't support indexOf?

Comment: I was just in the process of editing (to add in the `$.inArray()`) when your own edit popped up. So yeah, that's it.

Comment: @DavidThomas alright cool that'll work then. kinda wasn't sure for a second

Answer (score 0):

If all elements in your array must be unique, then I would really recommend using Underscore's array union:

```
arr = ["1", 2, "apple"];

console.log(_.union(arr, 3)); //["1", 2, "apple", 3]
console.log(_.union(arr, 2)); //["1", 2, "apple"]
```

Comment: keep in mind though, "union" is non-mutating. if you want to "push" into arr, do arr = _.union(arr, key)

Comment: Why use another library where there is already another one is capable to do this or without it.

Comment: Same reason as why you would use jQuery for DOM manipulation: Underscore is de facto the standard utility belt for any js project

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to use another library only for this because `jQuery` is already in use.

Comment: Why you are arguing that makes no sense, `jQuery` has  [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check the array or even it's not wise to use another library only for this tiny reason and `inArray` is better than `union` in this case and finally, this question is not tagged with `underscore` but `jQuery`.

Comment: I'm not arguing, I'm asking (as in, I was actually interested if jQuery had union or intersection functions)

Comment: Then, I really feel bad that I misunderstood your intention, so, I'm sorry for that. `jQuery` has `merge` for that and I was just trying to tell you that this is not tagged as `underscore` and not wise to use it either, in this case.

Comment: Don't feel bad! It's ok :) .merge doesn't do array intersection ($.merge([1,2],[2]) produces [1,2,2]). Anyways, I found a thread on jQuery forums about that: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-array-intersection-or-union . Looks like it's not built-in but there are some utilities

Comment: I think `union` sounds like making more in one bur not sure, `unique` is better word and I thought that.